# Python, Pandas. Converting from cumulative values to deltas

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have a pandas series of dates and cumulative values like this:

```
'2015-01-01': 1
'2015-01-02': 3
'2015-01-03': 7
'2015-01-04': 8
```

Can I use pandas to convert them in "deltas" like this?

```
'2015-01-01': 0   
'2015-01-02': 2
'2015-01-03': 4
'2015-01-04': 1
```

Or should I just do it manually?

Comment: Are the dates the index to your Series or are they values too? I.e. is the first value in the Series `"'2015-01-01': 1"` or simply `1`?

Comment: The dates are the index.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can just call [`diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.diff.html#pandas.Series.diff), the default period is `1`:

```
In [21]:

df['diff'] = df['Cumulative_Value'].diff()
df
Out[21]:
       Dates  Cumulative_Value  diff
0 2015-01-01                 1   NaN
1 2015-01-02                 3     2
2 2015-01-03                 7     4
3 2015-01-04                 8     1
```

You can also use [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html#pandas.Series.shift) which is a more general purpose operation that returns a series shifted by a period (again the default is 1), in this case though on this size dataset it is slower:

```
In [25]:

%timeit df['Cumulative_Value'].diff()
%timeit df['Cumulative_Value'] - df['Cumulative_Value'].shift()
%timeit df[['Cumulative_Value']].apply(lambda x: x - x.shift(), axis=1)
10000 loops, best of 3: 109 µs per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 330 µs per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 4.02 ms per loop
```

The last example shows how much slower looping over each row is (I've used a double `[[]]` to force it to return a dataframe so I can pass param `axis=1` which applies the lambda function row-wise) compared to the first 2 methods which are vectorised. Always seek a vectorised approach to take advantage of the significantly faster operations.

So you can see here that `diff` is ~4000x faster than looping over each row, as it is vectorised it will scale much better than a non-vectorised approach.

Comment: Thanks. Wondering why `diff` is not mentioned in this page? http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html

Comment: `diff` works on all series that are numerical dtypes as such it is a general function, you can always suggest a doc enhancement at [github](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues)