# How can I convert cumulative values to incremental values to a pandas dataframe with null values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, cumulative-sum

I have a pandas dataframe which has cumulative values like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {'Date':['2017-01-27','2017-01-28','2017-01-29','2017-01-30','2017-01-31','2017-02-01','2017-02-02','2017-02-03','2017-02-04','2017-02-05'],
'Kentucky':[1,4,5,7,np.NaN,np.NaN,10,np.NaN,12,13],
'New York':[np.NaN,2,np.NaN,7,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,9,np.NaN],
'California':[np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,1,np.NaN,2,np.NaN],
'Maine':[np.NaN,2,3,7,np.NaN,np.NaN,10,np.NaN,12,13]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

[image]

How can I convert the cumulative values to incremental values if the dataframe has null values? I have tried [incremental values conversion solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28129674/python-pandas-converting-from-cumulative-values-to-deltas) but it does not produce the desired result.

Comment: Just add `dropna()`to the solution you linked: `df['Kentucky'] = df['Kentucky'].dropna().diff()`

Comment: This is not a solution, you should replace with ceros.

Comment: Why *you should replace with zeros*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First convert to a data frame:

```
data = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Next use fillna's forward fill to account for the NaN issue. Below shows the code for Maine, but could be applied to the other states:

```
data['Maine_Inc_Values'] = data['Maine'].fillna(method='ffill').diff()
```

Then use .loc to correct for the first incremental value (which returns a NaN and not 2):

```
data.loc[data['Maine_Inc_Values'].isnull(), 'Maine_Inc_Values'] = data['Maine']
```

Results in:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.interpolate()` method to fill up `NaN` based on surrounding values, then use `.diff()` to get increments. This assumes the quantities change smoothly over time.

Taking back your example with date-based indexing (last line added):

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {'Date':['2017-01-27','2017-01-28','2017-01-29','2017-01-30','2017-01-31','2017-02-01','2017-02-02','2017-02-03','2017-02-04','2017-02-05'],
'Kentucky':[1,4,5,7,np.NaN,np.NaN,10,np.NaN,12,13],
'New York':[np.NaN,2,np.NaN,7,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,9,np.NaN],
'California':[np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,1,np.NaN,2,np.NaN],
'Maine':[np.NaN,2,3,7,np.NaN,np.NaN,10,np.NaN,12,13]}

# Turn to dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Set up dates as index to operate on similar-type columns
df = df.set_index("Date")
```

#### Proposed solution

```py
df.interpolate().diff().fillna(0)
```

#### Output

```bash
            Kentucky  New York  California  Maine
Date                                             
2017-01-27       0.0       0.0         0.0    0.0
2017-01-28       3.0       0.0         0.0    0.0
2017-01-29       1.0       2.5         0.0    1.0
2017-01-30       2.0       2.5         0.0    4.0
2017-01-31       1.0       0.4         0.0    1.0
2017-02-01       1.0       0.4         0.0    1.0
2017-02-02       1.0       0.4         0.0    1.0
2017-02-03       1.0       0.4         0.5    1.0
2017-02-04       1.0       0.4         0.5    1.0
2017-02-05       1.0       0.0         0.0    1.0
```